# Resizing content in a div inside flex box pushes other content outside of box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As part of my HTML5/CSS3 app, I need to implement zoomable image popup.  When the user clicks on a small image, a full-screen popup appears containing that image in the middle with a title above it and a button to close the popup below it.  Clicking on the image then removes any scaling and puts it full-size inside a box in the middle to allow scrolling - with title and "close" button staying above and below.

I'm using flex (for several reasons, including vertical centering content).  The overall popup works and looks fine.  Clicking on the image does increase it in size, but it resizes the box so that the "done" button is pushed below the overall popup.

Here's the [jsfiddle demonstrating the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ah09k8u4/1/)

I don't mind the fact that the box resizes - the more room to view/scroll the larger image - but I need to ensure that the button at the bottom stays put relative to the bottom edge of the popup.

My HTML looks like this (I used a random image for demonstration):

```
<div id="overlay" class="hidden">
    <div id="alsg">
        <div class="intro">Assist with ALS</div>
        <div class="box scrollable">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Male_monarch_butterfly.JPG" class="fit" />
        </div>

        <div class="popup-buttons">
            <div id="button-alsg-done" class="button button-state-action button-green right">Done</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- alsg -->
</div>
```

With the javascript being

```
$('img', '#alsg').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('fit');
});
```

There's a lot of CSS, unfortunately.  You'll note that there's a pretty bad mix of flex and old-school positioning.  This is because the app initially didn't use flex at all and I'm in a slow process of migrating/cleaning up now.

```
div#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 104;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

div#overlay > div {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
div#alsg {
    max-height: calc(100% - 40px) !important;
}

div#overlay div.intro {
    color: #FFF !important;
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div#overlay div.box, div.template div.box {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
div#alsg div.box {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto !important;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px !important;
}
div.box {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #27374A;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 3px solid #FBE96E;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.fit {
    max-width: calc(100% - 4px) !important;
    max-height: calc(100% - 4px) !important;
}

div.popup-buttons {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#overlay .button.right {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#button-alsg-done {
    margin-top: 10px;
    flex-basis: 25px;
}
div.button-green {
    background-color: #2CC55D;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
div.button-state-action {
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    width: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
div.button {
    height: 22px;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    width: 42px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```